# Consuming a Webservice (WSDL) using monodevelop C# on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, soap, mono, wsdl

How to consume a web service (WSDL-SOAP) on Linux using Mono with C#?

I have tried to add web service references to mono but it's not giving the reference list.

Please support,
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Internet is a great opportunity to find anything, if you have any problem then ask here.

Comment: Having the same issue. I followed the directions in other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126924/consuming-a-webservice-wsdl-using-monodevelop-c-sharp-on-4-0-on-windows-7-pro) but monodevelop/linux doesn't seem to like the local file and keeps wrapping the example url. In the end I used the wsdl command line.